# Possible to let the stored procedure run one by one even if multiple sessions are calling them in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql: multiple sessions want to get one record from the the table, but we need to make sure they don't interfere with each other. I could do it using message queue: put the data in a queue, and them let each session get data from the queue. But is it doable in postgresql? since it will be easier for SQL guys to cal stored procedure. Any way to configure a stored procedure so that no concurrent calling will happen, or use some special lock?

Comment: What, exactly, does "interfere with each other" mean to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making sure the stored procedure uses `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, which should prevent the same row in the table from being accessed by multiple transactions.

Per the *Postgres* doc:

> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be
>   locked as though for update. This prevents them from being modified or
>   deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That
>   is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE,
>   SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE or SELECT FOR KEY SHARE of
>   these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends. The FOR
>   UPDATE lock mode is also acquired by any DELETE on a row, and also by
>   an UPDATE that modifies the values on certain columns. Currently, the
>   set of columns considered for the UPDATE case are those that have an
>   unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key (so partial
>   indexes and expressional indexes are not considered), but this may
>   change in the future.

More [`SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) info.

So you don't end up locking all of the rows in the table at once (i.e. by `SELECT`ing *all* of the records), I would recommend you use `ORDER BY` to sort the table in a consistent manner, and then do a `LIMIT 1`, so that it only gets the next one in the queue. Also add a `WHERE` clause that checks for a certain column value (i.e. `processed`), and then once processed set the column to a value that will prevent the `WHERE` clause from picking it up.

Comment: Yup. Alternately you can `LOCK TABLE`, but this can be deadlock-prone due to lock upgrades. If you care about things like making sure work is completed before being marked as processed while still preserving concurrency, you'll want a real reliable task queue instead.